# Parse Clojure Command Line Args

Tags: clojure

I am trying to separate my cli options into a stand-alone namespace for starting up an HTTP server, and I am getting this error-

```
 clojure.lang.ArraySeq cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
```

In `main.clj`, this code works fine-

```
(ns served.main
  (:require [org.httpkit.server :refer [run-server]]
    [served.app.core :refer [handler]]
    [served.server.cli-options :refer [set-options]]
    [clojure.tools.cli :refer [parse-opts]])
    (:gen-class))

(def cli-options
 [
  ["-p" "--port PORT" "Port number"
  :default 5000 
  :parse-fn #(Integer/parseInt %)
  :validate [#(< 0 % 0x10000) "Must be a number between 0 and 65536"]]
  ])  

(defn -main [& args]
  (println "Server starting")
  (let [options (get (parse-opts args cli-options) :options)]
  ;;(let [options (set-options args)]
  (println (str options))
  (run-server handler options)))
```

It will work with the default options in `(def cli-options)` and it compiles correctly if I pass in arguments, such as `-p 7000`.

When I call the main function with the external namespace `served.server.cli-options` instead of `clojure.tools.cli` directly (i.e. switch the comment in `main`), I get the error only when passing in args.

That is, starting the server without arguments, e.g. `lein run` compiles fine and will print out the defaults. The error comes with `lein run -p 7000`.

After deleting `(def cli-options)` in `main` to avoid any global conflict, here is `served.server.cli-options`

```
(ns served.server.cli-options
  (:require [clojure.tools.cli :refer [parse-opts]]))

(def cli-options
  [
    ["-p" "--port PORT" "Port number"
    :default 5000 
    :parse-fn #(Integer/parseInt %)
    :validate [#(< 0 % 0x10000) "Must be a number between 0 and 65536"]]
  ])  

(defn set-options [& args]
  (let [options (get (parse-opts args cli-options) :options)]
  (println (str options))  
  options))
```

So far as I can tell, I copied the contents to the new namespace correctly. [Here](http://clojure.github.io/tools.cli/index.html#clojure.tools.cli/parse-opts) are the docs for `parse-opts`, [here](https://github.com/clojure/tools.cli) is the example that I am drawing from, and a similar but different SO issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30491335/3100284).

My question - how are the CLI args being transformed to throw casting error, and how do I fix it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the `&` in:

```
(defn set-options [& args]
```

`&` wraps up any additional arguments in a seq. Since you’ve already wrapped the program arguments once in `main`, you mustn’t do it again in the call to `set-options`.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks!